# HASKELL: How to get a list of figures of specified type?

Tags: haskell, types, tuples

I have the user data types like

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)
data Shape = Circle Point Float | 
         Rectangle Point Point | 
         Triangle Point Point Point |
         Label Point Font String deriving (Show)
```

And database like

```
database :: [Shape]
database = [(Circle (Point 2 5) 5), (Circle (Point 1 4) 3), (Circle (Point 8 3) 4),
    (Rectangle (Point 0 5) (Point 10 0)), (Rectangle (Point 3 5) (Point 10 0)),(Rectangle (Point 0 10) (Point 20 0)),
    (Triangle (Point 1 1) (Point 2 2) (Point 3 1)), (Triangle (Point 2 5) (Point 5 8) (Point 9 1))]
```

So how can i get figures of specified type from this?

Comment: Terminological note: `Shape` is a type. `Circle`, `Rectangle`, `Triangle`, and `Label` are constructors.  Lists  can only contain values of a single type.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a predicate, like

```
isCircle :: Shape -> Bool
isCircle (Circle _ _) = True
isCircle _ = False
```

Then, filter by it:

```
databaseCircles = filter isCircle database
```

However, I'd advise you to decompose your types a bit:

```
data Circle = Circle Point Float
data Rectangle = Rectangle Point Point
data Triangle = Triangle Point Point Point
data Label = Label Point Font String
data Shape = CircleShape Circle | RectangleShape Rectangle
    | TriangleShape Triangle | LabelShape Label
```

So that you can have a type-safe list of circles (or rectangles, or etc.):

```
getMaybeCircle:: Shape -> Maybe Circle
getMaybeCircle (CircleShape c) = Just c
getMaybeCircle _ = Nothing

filterCircles :: [Shape] -> [Circle]
filterCircles = catMaybes . map getMaybeCircle
```

Note: [`catMaybes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) is from [`Data.Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html).

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension also works

```
[ s | s@(Circle _ _) <- database ]
```